# angularjs issue with special character `®`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an expression in angularjs to replace special character Registered with surrounding sup tags.

```
replace(/®/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
```

But in the developer tools, it is changing the ® to a symbol � (a question mark symbol)

```
.replace(/�/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>');
```

Not sure if the issue is with the angularjs header content-type. Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: `But in the developer tools....` <= so sounds like it is an issue in the tool....

Comment: Have you tried replacing it with the entities written out in full? .replace(/R/, '<sup>&#174;</sup>') for example? (or &reg; or &circledR; or &#x000AE;)

Comment: Use `.replace(/\u00ae/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.replace(/\u00ae/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')`

Because `\u00ae` = ®

For more information,

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - String (Escape Notation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - ES6 Tagged template literals and escape sequences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals_and_escape_sequences)

```js
var x = "\u00ae"
var y = x.replace(/\u00ae/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
console.log("x=",x);
console.log("y=",y);

var x1 = '®';
var y1 = x.replace(/\u00ae/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
console.log("x1=",x1);
console.log("x1= Ox00%s",x1.charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
console.log("y1=",y1);
```

Comment: Thanks georgeawg. Your solution worked great for me!!